# should i save a db table in a hash map to speed up my program

Tags: java, hashtable, polling

I have a polling loop that accesses devices, some of the devices are linked together and as such when one of the linked devices is polled its state must be copied to the other linked device.

I am trying to speed up the process of updating the second linked device. if device 4 is linked to device 5 it is fast but if device 5 is polled and a change found it has to wait till the polling loop is completed and started again.

My idea is to check as part of the poll if the device is linked so it can be updated immediately. The information on what devices are linked is stored in the database and making a call to the database for every poll will slow down the system dramatically I think so what I wanted to do was create a hash table of the table and check that instead.

so here are my questions

1. would this idea work ?
2. would the hash table be faster than the database checks ?
3. how often should I recreate the hash table, the program will run for weeks at a time ?
4. is this the best way of doing this. are there other ways to speed up a polling loop ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash table if searching is a priority. Hash tables provide very quick search mechanisms when searching by key, and fairly good searching when searching by value
Use a hash table if you want to be able to remove specific elements (use the Remove method)
Use a hash table when the order the elements is stored is irrelevant to you.
Don't use a hash table if you need the elements in some specific order. You cannot rely on how a Hashtable will sort its elements
Don't use a hash table if you need to insert an element in a particular location
Don't use a hash table if you want to store multiple keys with the same value. All keys inside a hash table must be unique.

Comment: From an implementation standpoint, I'd actually stick to the class HashMap over HashTable. (and HashSet if you want to guarantee it as a "set" of unique values).